# Как убрать промежутки между горизонтальными li?

Tags: css, css3, адаптивная-верстка, sass, scss

Как избавится от промежутков между горизонтальными li?

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.svg-icon {
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.rect {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 background: #262626;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
 <ul class="rating-info-container">
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 вариант

parent - `font-size: 0;`
child - `font-size: XXXpx`; <--- если нужно

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.rating-info-container{
    font-size: 0;
}
.svg-icon {
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
 display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.rect {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 background: #262626;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
 <ul class="rating-info-container">
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

2 вариант

Записать в одну строку

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.svg-icon {
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.rect {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 background: #262626;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
 <ul class="rating-info-container">
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li><li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li><li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

3 вариант

не закрывать li

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.svg-icon {
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.rect {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 background: #262626;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
 <ul class="rating-info-container">
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div>
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div>
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div>
 </ul>
</div>
```

P.S. Закройте тег `ul`

Comment: Просто великолепный ответ! Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul {
  display: inline-table;
}
.svg-icon {
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.rect {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 background: #262626;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
 <ul class="rating-info-container">
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А у Вас что-то не работает пример :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.svg-icon {
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
 float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.rect {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 background: #262626;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
 <ul class="rating-info-container">
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
  <li class="svg-icon"><div class="rect"></div></li>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]